# How to extract fields from 'Layout' JSON file of Power BI tool with Python?

Tags: python, json, powerbi, data-extraction, nested-json

I request a code modification that extracts columns from a (nested) JSON file inside a '.PBIX' file (Power BI tool) in Python. The details are below:

- Original code to extract some columns written by Mr [Umberto Grando](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10656916/umberto-grando):
- Code on GitHub: https://github.com/Inzaniak/pybistuff/tree/master/pbixExtractor
- Explanation of the code on Medium: https://python.plainenglish.io/extracting-measures-and-fields-from-a-power-bi-report-in-python-1b928d9fb128
- I extracted the Layout file for your convenience in Google Drive: https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1Z5cqgE-iuS0__G5hCl7Ge-MZW9WKmJu7?usp=sharing

**Request:**

- I need to extract the **'visualType'** field as well in a similar format in the GitHub code above for Business Documentation. To be able to extract parameters like this in a table automatically will save hours of time in documentation.

I tried:

- JS Beautify
  JSON dumps, JSON LOADS, JSON Normalize, Different Encoding types, Adding ['visualTypes'] in code but didn't know how to append. I have trouble understanding the structure of the JSON file here, too.

Other tries :

```
!cd "path/Layout"
import json

# Opening JSON file
f = open('path/Layout', encoding='utf-16 le')

# returns JSON object as
# a dictionary
data = json.load(f)

# Iterating through the json
# list
for i in data:
    print(i)
```

###Output: ###

- id sections pods config reportId resourcePackages layoutOptimization
  publicCustomVisuals

Comment: You need to wash this structure it is a mix of json and json strings, You have 2 "Layout" fields embeded into json strings. it is a good excersise

Comment: Thanks for your quick response. I'll also continue to learn the things required to understand and solve the problem. Have a good day.

Answer (score 0):

Main reason this was downwoted what that you did not post any code or errors when you tried to solve this.

When I tried I got this error:
`json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting property name enclosed in double quotes: line 1 column 2 (char 1)`

and:
`UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xa9 in position 9380: invalid start byte`

This you can most likely find lots of answers to with google:

When you see byte errors in `json.load()` it is most likely encoding, so chardet will help you:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import json
import chardet
raw = "C:\\Users\\mobj\\Downloads\\Layout"

with open(raw, 'rb') as FI:
    print(chardet.detect(FI.read()))

dat = {}
# encoding from chardet:
with open(raw, 'r', encoding='utf-16le', errors='ignore') as FI:
    dat = json.load(FI)

print(json.dumps(dat, indent=2, sort_keys=True))
```

Comment: Thanks so much for this response and your time. I deeply appreciate it. In my code, the error was caused by not exactly inputting 'encoding='utf-16 le' while reading the JSON file of PBIX. The original author Mr Grando successfully avoided this by always keeping that line while reading JSON file in python, as I understand it.